# Write value for template using erb+Chef if value is set

Tags: ruby, erb, chef-infra, chef-recipe

What's the cleanest way to write logic like this in erb for Chef?

```rb
<% if node[:ipynb][:NotebookApp][:certfile] %>
   c.NotebookApp.certfile = <%= node[:ipynb][:NotebookApp][:certfile] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would rewrite `unless node[:ipynb][:NotebookApp][:certfile].nil?` as `if node[:ipynb][:NotebookApp][:certfile]` because it is much cleaner.

Comment: Two years later and I've updated the above @timurb. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your approach, but if you want a one-liner, this should work:

```
<%= "c.NotebookApp.certfile = #{node[:ipynb][:NotebookApp][:certfile]}" if node[:ipynb][:NotebookApp][:certfile] %>
```

For boolean expressions in Ruby, `nil` and `false` values translate as `false`, everything else is `true`. If you have any value in `node[:ipynb][:NotebookApp][:certfile]`, it will evaluate to true and print the string. Otherwise, it will print nothing.

Comment: Nothing wrong per se, I'm just a bit new to Ruby and wanted to find out if there were best practice Rubyisms/Chefisms. I have quite a few config lines like these and I was tempted to right a function for them. Thanks @cbl!

Comment: Since nil evaluates to false, I'm going to go with
`<% if node[:ipynb][:NotebookApp][:certfile] %>
    c.NotebookApp.certfile = <%= node[:ipynb][:NotebookApp][:certfile] %>
<% end %>`